# How to use modularized jars in a not modularized application?

Tags: java, java-module, unnamed-module

In various places i saw the following information: The classes inside the **the unnamed** module are allowed to read exported packages on the **module path**.

Inside the directory src/calculators i have the module-info.java file:

```
module calculators {
  exports calculators;
}
```

Inside the directory src/calculators/calculators i have the InterestCalculator.java file:

```
package calculators;

public interface InterestCalculator {

  public double calculate(double principle, double rate, double time);
}
```

I have compiled the module with the following command:

```
java --module-source-path src --module calculators -d out
```

And then i have packaged the compiled module with the following command:

```
jar --create --file calculators.jar -C out/calculators/ .
```

Now my not modularized application have the following classes ( in the same dir ):

```
import calculators.InterestCalculator;

class SimpleInterestCalculator implements InterestCalculator {

  public double calculate(double principle, double rate, double time){
    return principle * rate * time;
  }
}
```

```
import calculators.InterestCalculator;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InterestCalculator interestCalculator = new SimpleInterestCalculator();

  }
}
```

When i try to compile my application using the module with the command:

```
javac --module-path calculators.jar  *.java
```

I got the error:

```
Main.java:1: error: package calculators is not visible
import calculators.InterestCalculator;
       ^
  (package calculators is declared in module calculators, which is not in the module graph)
SimpleInterestCalculator.java:1: error: package calculators is not visible
import calculators.InterestCalculator;
       ^
  (package calculators is declared in module calculators, which is not in the module graph)
2 errors
```

Why? Should not the application classes be able to read the exported packages? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application code is not a module there's nothing in the environment telling Java to resolve the `calculators` module. This results in the classes not being found despite placing the JAR file on the module-path. If you want to continue using the module-path for your library, you need to use:

```
javac --module-path calculators.jar --add-modules calculators <rest-of-command>
```

Notice the `--add-modules calculators` argument. This makes the `calculators` module a root, forcing it and all its `requires` dependencies (transitively) into the module graph. If your application was to be made modular:

```java
module app {
  requires calculators;
}
```

Then you would no longer need `--add-modules` because the `app` module would be a root and it requires the `calculators` module.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Your last command line should be:

```
javac --class-path calculators.jar  *.java
```

instead of:

```
javac --module-path calculators.jar  *.java
```

**Why?**

If you are compiling a *non-modular* application, you should not use `--module-path` option, but `--class-path` (or the shorter version: `-cp`).

Remember that a modular JAR still works like a regular JAR. It just contains some more information for modular applications.